# How do I override Deployment package defaults in GCP Deployment Manager?

Tags: google-deployment-manager, wurfl

I would like to create an instance of [WURFL Microservice Basic from the GCP Marketplace](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/product/scientiamobile-public/wurfl-microservice-basic?project=msm-groupdata-datalake-prod) however I'd like to do that programatically so that I can reproduce it if required.

I downloaded the deployment zip file from the above linked page:
[image]

and unzipped it onto my machine, so here I have the code for creating the WURFL solution:

[image]

The file test_config.yaml contains pertinent information about my deployment, I changed the zone to the zone that I want to deploy to:

```yaml
imports:
- path: wurfl-microservice-basic.jinja

resources:
- name: wurfl-microservice-basic
  type: wurfl-microservice-basic.jinja
  properties:
    zone: europe-west2-a
```

Now I try and deploy using command:

```sh
gcloud deployment-manager deployments create \
  wurfl \
  --project xxxxxxx \
  --config test_config.yaml
```

which fails with error:

> The fingerprint of the deployment is b'EciU4ogM5bd10ff_MnHsVQ=='
> Waiting for create [operation-1632242107865-5cc83fb06da45-f22cec62-c9ce6955]...failed.
>
> ERROR: (gcloud.deployment-manager.deployments.create) Error in Operation [operation-1632242107865-5cc83fb06da45-f22cec62-c9ce6955]: errors:
>
> - code: RESOURCE_ERROR
>   location: /deployments/wurfl/resources/wurfl-vm
>   message: "{"ResourceType":"compute.v1.instance","ResourceErrorCode":"400"
>   ,"ResourceErrorMessage":{"code":400,"errors":[{"domain":"global","
>   message":"Invalid value for field 'resource.networkInterfaces[0].network': 'https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/xxxxxxx/global/networks/default'.
>   \ The referenced network resource cannot be found.","reason":"invalid"}],"
>   message":"Invalid value for field 'resource.networkInterfaces[0].network': 'https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/xxxxxxx/global/networks/default'.
>   \ The referenced network resource cannot be found.","statusMessage":"Bad Request"
>   ,"requestPath":"https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/xxxxxxx/zones/europe-west2-a/instances"
>   ,"httpMethod":"POST"}}"

(Notice in the last line that it correctly refers to `europe-west2` as per my change)

The error makes sense, this project does not have a default network, it has an alternate network that I created and I'd like to override the default setting for network but I can't figure out how.

In **vm_instance.py.schema** I can see that networks are defined in a yaml list like so:

```yaml
  networks:
    description: List of Networks for each network interface of this VM
    type: array
    default:
    - default
```

So I tried changing the networks in a similar way to where I set the zone:

```yaml
imports:
- path: wurfl-microservice-basic.jinja

resources:
- name: wurfl-microservice-basic
  type: wurfl-microservice-basic.jinja
  properties:
    zone: europe-west2-a
    networks:
      - mynetwork
```

but that resulted in the same error. I also tried modifying **vm_instance.py.schema** with the correct network name but that didn't have any affect either.

Please can someone tell me how I can override a default (in this case the network) so that I can deploy this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out, this is what was required

```
imports:
- path: wurfl-microservice-basic.jinja

resources:
- name: wurfl-microservice-basic
  type: wurfl-microservice-basic.jinja
  properties:
    zone: europe-west2-a
    network: mynetwork
    subnetwork: mysubnetwork
```